# Insert page number in each page of PDF file via Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

Currently I'm working in a feature that will insert page number in PDFs via ghostscript. As first approach I tried to follow same commands as I did for inserting watermark in each file's page - as follows:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf watermark.ps in.pdf
```

In this case, watermark will be printed in every file's page - which is the behaviour I expected. However, for printing page number in each page is an incremental number which will be printed in every page, e.g, for each page a different number should be printed. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
<<
   /EndPage
   {
     2 eq { pop false }
     {
         gsave      
         /Arial 8 selectfont
         550 820 moveto (page 1) show
         grestore
         true
     } ifelse
   } bind
>> setpagedevice
```

And the command to call this is almost the same for watermark, just changing the second parameter:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf pages.ps in.pdf
```

I'm trying to insert parameters to this "pages.ps" file in order to print pages dynamically. Something like this:

```
550 820 moveto (attr[0]) show
```

And call via command line like this:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf pages.ps "pageNumber" in.pdf
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work!

I'm struggling this for days and any help would be appreciated. Any other approach will be helpful as well.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your command line, It seems to me that you're trying to pass arguments into
the postscript program from the command line. There are a few ways to do this.

### Using `ARGUMENTS`

Ghostscript has a special behavior when you invoke with the `--` argument.

```
$ gs -q -- prog.ps 1 2 3
```

Then the program can access these arguments as an array of strings called `ARGUMENTS`.

```
%!
ARGUMENTS ==
```

This program will print

```
[ (1) (2) (3) ]
```

for the above input.

### Using `-d` or `-s`

This way is probably better for your needs. You can use `-sname=string` to perform the equivalent of `/name (string) def` before proceeding with the next element of the command line. Use `-s` for strings and `-d` for any other kind of postscript token that needs to be scanned and interpreted.

So probably you want to do something like this:

```
$ gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf -sattr=pageNumber pages.ps in.pdf
```

Then page.ps can access this string simply as `attr`. PostScript array indexing doesn't use `[0]` like that anyway, instead using the `get` operator.

### Using `-c`

You could also use the `-c` option to execute a small fragment like `-c"/attr (pageNumber) def"`.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I wanted! Second option suited perfectly for my case. Thanks a lot sir o/

Comment: could you please explain this bit.

Comment: @rahim.nagori Which part?

Comment: pageNumber and pages.ps

Comment: `pages.ps` is the name of the postscript file from the question above. `pageNumber` is a string that we want to pass into the postscript program defined as the name `/attr`. Then the code in pages.ps can access this string. ... Does that help?

Comment: I've also written [a much longer post about passing configuration data into a postscript program.](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/BICCm088vqo/discussion) There are lots more ways than just the 3 described here..